How to scrape all webpages in a website for specific content
I am trying to find all the profiles with a keyword on a website.
So I am looking for the soccer players with Jamaica as their second nationality which cannot be done with a simple query through the website.
The profiles are stored in the following format:
https://www.soccerdonna.de/en/[PERSON_NAME]/profil/[VARIABLE].html
for instance
https://www.soccerdonna.de/en/liya-brooks/profil/spieler_69968.html
And for each profile, I am looking for keyword "Jamaica".
I have tried beautifulsoap library but it does not find all the profiles and it only finds the keywords in a specific page provided to it and it does not return anything.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extract_profiles_with_keyword(url, keyword):
    # Fetch webpage content
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        profiles = []

        # Find all profile elements
        profile_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='table-responsive')

        # Iterate through profile elements
        for profile_element in profile_elements:
            # Check if keyword is present in profile text
            if keyword.lower() in profile_element.text.lower():
                profiles.append(profile_element.text.strip())

        return profiles
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch the webpage.")
        return None


# URL of the website
url = "https://www.soccerdonna.de/en"

# Keyword to search for
keyword = "Jamaica"

# Extract profiles with the keyword
profiles = extract_profiles_with_keyword(url, keyword)

# Print the profiles
if profiles:
    for profile in profiles:
        print(profile)
else:
    print("No profiles found.")


Here is an example how you can get info about a player if you don't know her name (you have to increase the spieler_<ID> in the URL):
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.soccerdonna.de/en/NOT-IMPORTANT/profil/spieler_{number}.html"

for number in range(1, 10):  # <-- increase number here for more players
    url = base_url.format(number=number)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    name = soup.select_one(".tabelle_spieler h1")
    print(url)
    print(name.text.strip())

    for tr in soup.select(".tabelle_grafik .tabelle_spieler tr"):
        k, v = [
            td.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ").strip(":") for td in tr.select("td")
        ]
        print(f"{k:<50} {v}")
    print()

Prints:

...

https://www.soccerdonna.de/en/NOT-IMPORTANT/profil/spieler_7.html
Danesha Adams
Date of birth                                      06.06.1986
Place of birth                                     Bellflower, California
Age                                                37
Name in native country                             Danesha La Vonne Adams
Height                                             1,68
Nationality                                        United States
Position                                           Striker
Foot                                               right
Last match                                         07.11.2015 for Medkila

https://www.soccerdonna.de/en/NOT-IMPORTANT/profil/spieler_8.html
Claudia Aelker
Date of birth                                      25.01.1971
Age                                                53
Height                                             1,63
Nationality                                        Germany
Position                                           Defence
Last match                                         05.09.2004 for Heike Rheine

...


You can store this info to pandas DataFrame for example, save it as CSV and as final step do filtering (e.g. for word "Jamaica")
